# Laravel dusk vagrant box DesiredCapabilities::__construct()

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

Dusk issue
running Vagrant box with custom url on my mac. I had to edit `DuskTestCase.php` and replace `http://localhost:9515` with `$this->local` = `http://mysite.dev`.
`$php artisan dusk tests/Browser/LoginTest.php` outputs following error:

```
Tests\Browser\LoginTest::testLogin
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php on line 127

/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.php:33
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:127
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/tests/DuskTestCase.php:46
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:210
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:762
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:211
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:117
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:89
/Users/gmylonas/Vagrant Projects/mywebsite/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:23
```

When I replace `$this->local` = `http://www.google.com:80` and `$browser->visit('/')->dump();` it dumps the content of google page!
`$this->local` = `http://localhost:9515` will dump empty page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

:question: Why it won’t work on my box url and how to solve it?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that you shouldn't update `http://localhost:9515` to anything else. This is selenium driver and by default it's using this port and it should work without any problem.

By default when running:

```
$browser->visit('/')
```

it should visit the main url of your page without any other changes. However depending on your application you might need to set APP_URL in your `.env` file  especially when your application makes some domain checks.

Comment: i don't get it.